# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout (HELP)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

i'm building my first ever app in Android Studio. The purpose of the app is to connect to my Drupal website API and take data from it.

I have no visisble errors in my code but when i use logcat it keeps coming up with the following error:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

This is some of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExampleAdapter.onItemClickListener {

public static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "title";
public static final String EXTRA_BODY = "body";
public static final String EXTRA_LINK = "link";


private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJSON();


}
```

I already viewed similar questions on Stack but none of them fixed it.

Comment: Yigit Boyar (the dev in google behind recyclerView ) said "you can ignore it. or if u want to get rid of it, set an empty adapter when you initialize RecyclerView". I just ignore it ti this day. it's not important

Comment: I can't ignore it since the app doesn't display anything right now ^^

Comment: Ohh. Then, definitely the problem is not in this error. post your adapter  class code and activity's whole code please. For instance, check if your getItemCount() is not returning 0, and that you are calling notifyDatasetChanged() after submitting list to your adapter.

Comment: Adapter     https://pastebin.com/rBZwkU7E
MainActivity   https://pastebin.com/S88WwGW9

Answer (score 0):

you don't set mRecyclerView to your adapter

`mExampleAdapter.adapter = your adaper`

Comment: I did here: 

mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
                            mExampleAdapter.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this, new ExampleAdapter.onItemClickListener() {